# Running different data based on the input for Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am running a Shiny Apps which takes an input from the user. After taking the user input, it has to change the output accordingly.

The code looks like this:

```
#Shiny Header/Sidebar/Body
sidebar=dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "1", icon = icon("bar-chart")),
  selectInput("Category", "Select Desk", c("desk1", "desk2"))
))
body=dashboardBody(
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "Risk",uiOutput('output1'),
                    fluidRow(column(width = 3,box(title = "Summary of EQ Delta", width = NULL, collapsible = TRUE, solidheader = TRUE,status = "primary",tableOutput("EOD"))),column(width = 3,box(title = "Summary of FX Delta", width = NULL,  collapsible = TRUE, solidheader = TRUE,status = "primary",tableOutput("FX")))),
                    fluidRow(column(width = 8,box(title = "Exposures by Indices", width = NULL, collapsible = TRUE, solidheader = TRUE,status = "primary",plotOutput("Chart1"))))
                   )
          )
)
ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

#Shiny Server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  if(input$RiskCategory == "desk 1")
  (
     observeEvent(reactiveTimer(30000)(),{ # Trigger every 30 seconds
        source("script1.R")
    })
    output$output1 <- renderUI({
        invalidateLater(30000, session)
        h1(paste("Desk1"))
    })
  )
  else
  (
    print("desk2")
  )  
}
```

The program stops running when the script is as such. How do you control the output by the user input? Need some guidance.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at tutorials on shiny, particularly ones about [reactivity](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/); your use of `input$RiskCategory` needs to be within a `reactive` or `observe` (or related) block, not by itself within the server function.

Comment: can show an example of how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example this might help.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({


    data <- f1

    if (input$RiskCategory!= "All") {

        data <- data[data$RiskCategory== input$RiskCategory,]

    }

     data
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, but I need to render output in the if-else